# Codenameone App simulator launches @ wrong UI

Tags: java, user-interface, codenameone

I have three UI screens in my App.

Main (Login screen)
Register
Home

After clicking the login button on the main screen, user goes to Home. However since yesterday something happened and simulator automatically launches to the home screen without going to the login screen first.

I am not sure what I messed up, please help.

Here is my environment:

Windows 7 Ultimate
Java 1.7_05
Eclipse Luna (4.4.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after poking around in GUI Builder. In the codename GUI editor, click on the UI that you want to be the first one, In the properties part, click "Preview & Misc" -> "Initial form". This will make the UI the first to appear in the app.

Hope this helps someone who has run into similar issue.